# Gang of four patterns usage in automation frameworks

Tags: testing, design-patterns, automation, gang-of-four

I would like to know which Gang of four design patterns may have important applications when developing an automation framework.

For example Page Object Model (not a Gof pattern btw) is one of the most commonly used design patterns which are incorporated while developing automation frameworks.

In the similar context, I would like to know which of Gof patterns are commonly considered.

Lastly, it could be for any type of automation framework (Key-word, data driven etc).

Thanks.

Comment: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) are

> general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design.

so they will be applied regardless you're

> developing an automation framework.

or not. A very good and useful book of [xUnit patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/) will give you a guidance, as summary:

[image]

Another thing to turn to are those blogs:

- [myqaengineering](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/) with stuff like Hybrid UI test framework, Enterprise Meta API Test framework, Selenium layout image verification and How to test your Data WareHouse
- [automatetheplanet](http://automatetheplanet.com/compelling-sunday-23082015/) with stuff like Decorator, Observer, Strategy, Sigleton design patterns and their place in automation

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the xUnit patterns link. Just what I was looking for.